# Parse unicode characters from HTML element in Python

Tags: python, unicode, html-parsing, lxml

I have the following code to parse HTML sites. This returns an HTML element object. I would like to run this code on several machines so it's important for me to implement proxy when someone tries to run it from behind a proxy.

```
from lxml.html import parse

def parsepage(url):
if proxy:
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":proxy})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support,urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    site = parse(conn).getroot()
else:
    site = parse(url).getroot()
return site
```

After it returns the HTML element I get data from the object by using Xpath expressions like this:

```
element = site.xpath(expression)
```

The problem is that the result contains non-unicode data, which contains escape characters. E.g.:

> \xe1ci\xf3s kombi

I tried this implementation as well but this one gives me an error:

```
def parsepage(url):
if proxy:
    proxy_support = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http":proxy})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_support,urllib2.HTTPHandler)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    rawdata = conn.read()
    parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8")
    site = etree.HTML(rawdata, parser=parser)
else:
    site = parse(url).getroot()
return site
```

And the error message is:

> 'utf8' decode can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 4: invalid continuation byte

The site is using iso-8859-2 charset.

Is there a way to convert non-unicode characters to unicode with one of the parsing methods listed above? Or maybe I'm getting something wrong and I'm getting the data in a correct format but I have problem with the representation.

Should I use lxml.fromstring instead and use the encoding parameter?

Thanks,
g0m3z

Solution:

Actually there was no problem with my code but the representation of data. The first code implementation works fine.

I load the result to a dictionary and when I print the whole dictionary at one shot it shows unicode characters incorrectly. However, if I print only one item of the result dictionary based on a key it represents the unicode characters correctly. So it works! Interesting. Thanks for everyone on this thread for valuable comments!

Comment: Why are you telling the parser that the encoding is utf-8 when you know it is iso-8859-2?  Try using `parser = etree.HTMLParser(encoding="iso-8859-2")` and see if that solves your problems.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I tried with iso-8859-2 encoding but I still got escape characters

Comment: +1 For actually using a parser and not trying to parse HTML with regex as 90% of SO users love to do.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the actual character encoding from the HTTP-headers (or HTML-meta-tags) and not guess it. This way you can avoid decoding errors.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I tried with iso-8859-2 encoding but I still got escape characters.

Comment: In theory, this should be the way to do it. Unfortunately, hosting companies often don't give webmasters the ability to change charset information in HTTP headers, and furthermore, web designers are often inconsistent in using meta elements (blame cargo cult coding). Unless you know the site to be compliant in these areas, you may have to try auto-detecting encoding (in a similar situation, we had a list of encodings which we tried in order, taking the first one that decoded without raising an exception. Not really a good solution; in hindsight I'd probably use chardet or some similar library)

Comment: @Gomez As I said, don't try to guess it, at least try to infer it.

Comment: @brjaga Sad, but true. But this also leaves room for cases where you simply cannot guess the encoding. But I have no idea how OP would like to proceed in those cases.

Comment: @brjaga Thanks for your prompt reply! In this case I guess there might be something with the proxy. I'll try to run it by bypassing the proxy and let you know the result.

Comment: @brjaga I load the result to a dictionary and when I print the whole dictionary at one shot it shows unicode characters incorrectly. However, if I print only one item of the result dictionary based on a key it represents the unicode characters correctly. So it works! Interesting. Thanks for everyone on this thread for valuable comments!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a library for de parsing of the request. I recomend you BeautifulSoup. This will handle with all the problems with the encode and is very easy to use it.

Comment: Thanks but I would like to keep it simple and fast. I found lxml extremely fast.